# Excel number formatting with brackets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I hope someone can help me.

I am trying to use a custom format on a cell which concatenates two other cells to show a value with the change in brackets e.g. "1234 (+2)" or 1234 (-1). I have managed to get it to a point where it will show '-' when it is a negative number but haven't been able to get a '+' sign for positive numbers. Also, when the number is 0 it shows as 0 (0) when ideally I would want this to just show as '-'.

I really hope someone can help me as I've been searching for a while for a solution! I am using Excel 2010 if that makes a difference.

Thank you inadvance.

Comment: Sounds like you need to nest an if statement (or several) into your concatenate so that it will pull up the correct sign for you. If you need more help, then please include an more detailed example of your data (what data is contained in the cells you are trying to concatenate, looks like you describe the result).

Comment: You're creating a character string so you need to treat everything that isn't a digit explicitly as characters by putting them in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, I used a combination of nested IF statements and TEXT conversions to get a 1,000 separator. For anyone with a similar problem here is the solution I came up with. =IF(B20=0,"-",CONCATENATE(TEXT(B20,"#,###")," (",IF(B20-B36>=0,"+",""),B20-B36,")"))

Obviously change the cell references to fit your spreadsheet. This should give a result as 1,234 (+10) for example.